# Why a subspace is assumed instead of a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why does the following theorem start with "Let $\{u_1, ..., u_p\}$ be an orthogonal basis for a subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$" instead of "Let $\{u_1, ..., u_p\}$ be an orthogonal basis for a vector space $W$". In other words, what is the point for starting with a subspace of a vector space instead of a vector space?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Every space is itself a subspace -- this result is simply stronger.

Comment: We start with a subspace since we are trying to express a vector in the subspace in that form

Comment: They probably intend to study subspaces with what follows this statement.

Comment: It is a nice formula to calculate the coefficients of any linear combination in a given vector subspace of the space $\mathbb R^n$. If they gave it for  $\mathbb R^n$, it would not have to be valid for any subspace, but instead this statement is valid for the entire space in particular. Note that the orthogonality condition of the given vectors is very important here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the *inner product* (dot product) of $\Bbb R^n$, and in particular *orthogonality* are used in the statement, which are not given in an abstract vector space.

Well, indeed, one could say 'let $W$ be an inner product space with orthogonal basis $u_1,\dots,u_p$', but probably abstract inner product spaces were not yet introduced in the course/book.